# Host WCF service using top shelf and windsor castle

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, topshelf, windsor-facilities

I am using Topshelf to run my wcf service and windsor castle for dependency injection. Problem it when I run the host program directly, it runs fine as console host but the same program gives this error while trying to start it as windows service.

```
Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost Error: 0 : The service failed to start., System.Invalid
OperationException: Cannot start service MyService on computer '.'. ---> Sy
stem.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not respond to the start or
control request in a timely fashion
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
   at Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsHostEnvironment.StartService(String servic
eName, TimeSpan startTimeOut)
   at Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost.Run()
```

Below is my implementation :-

```
      class Program{
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        var boot = new ServiceInstaller();

        HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<Program>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new Program());
                s.WhenStarted(p => p.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(p => p.Stop());
            });
            x.DependsOnMsSql();
            x.StartAutomatically();

            x.SetDisplayName("My Service");
            x.SetServiceName("MyService");
        });
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {

                _serviceProvider = typeof(IMyService).AssemblyQualifiedName;
                LogMessage(LogLevel.INFO, _serviceProvider, null);
                if (_serviceProvider == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Failed to start service: {0}", _serviceProvider));
                }
                _serviceHost = new DefaultServiceHostFactory().CreateServiceHost(_serviceProvider, new Uri[0]);
                _serviceHost.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage(LogLevel.ERROR, "Error occurred while starting My Service", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }


        public void Stop()
        {

            try
            {

                _serviceHost.Close();

                _serviceHost = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogMessage(LogLevel.ERROR, "Error occurred while stopping My service ", ex);
                throw;
            }

        }
 }
public Class ServiceInstaller{
public static IWindsorContainer Container { get; private set; }

        public ServiceInstaller()
        {
            try
            {
                Container = new WindsorContainer();
                Container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(Container));


                Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Register
                (
                     Component.For<IDependency>().ImplementedBy<Dependency>().LifestyleTransient(),
                     Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyService>().LifestyleTransient()
                );

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (Container != null)
                {
                    Container.Dispose();
                    Container = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably the code in Start throws an exception when running as a service. Try putting a log message after each statement and before the first to see which line is throwing.

Comment: That is probably true but why it runs fine when debugging through Visual studio or just running it in the bin folder.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Event Logs to see if the exception is logged there?

Comment: yes this is exception logged into windows event log Application: MyServiceHost.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.ComponentActivatorException Stack: at MyServiceHost.Program.Main(System.String[])

Comment: Can you post your Dependency and MyService classes? I suspect the issue is with them.

Comment: I found that in my dependency class I have database call in the constructor, on commenting it, everything runs fine without any problem. I think Castle windsor is getting confused when my constructor is trying to access database.
@RagtimeWilly: Thanks for the hint !

Comment: It is strange though why it is able to resolve the dependency when running directly not when trying to start as windows service. Also I wanted to make the database call only once, that is the reason of having that call in constructor. Any hint where do I make that call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in my injected dependency I have code to access database in the constructor. Once I removed that code, it was working fine. Don't know why the same code runs fine when running using console host. I guess some problem with castle windsor.